# Arrangement of table for Game Theory

Tags: tables, game-tree

I am trying to organize a table, however I cannot make it look the way I want. I would like everything wrapped in lines until the labels Player 1 and Player 2. Here is what I have written:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc|c|c|c|}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\omega_1} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\color{blue}Player 2}\\
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$p$}
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$1-p$}\\
      \cline{3-4} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a_2$}  
      & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$b_2$} \\
        \cline{3-4} 
      \multirow{2}*{\color{red}Player 1}
      \multirow{1}*{q}
      \multirow{2}*{1-q}
        & $a_1$ 
             & $\textbf{(\color{red}{0}\color{black},\color{blue}{0}\color{black})}$ 
             & $(\color{red}{6}\color{black},\color{blue}{-3}\color{black})$ \\
            \cline{3-4}
        & $b_1$ 
              & $(\color{red}{-3} \color{black},\color{blue}{6}\color{black})$ 
              & $(\color{red}{5} \color{black},\color{blue}{5}\color{black})$ \\
        \cline{3-4}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

In this respect I would need as well the label q and 1-q in ahead of the a_1 and a_2 labels, in the same way p and 1-p are organized.

After this is organized I need to do a probability tree that marks the probability values on the branches and then displays the two tables on both ends (assume two identical tables with p=1/2)

**edit: as requested, here is a complete example of my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4 paper]{article}

          \usepackage{multicol} %Needed for \PDgame
          \usepackage{multirow}
          \usepackage{wrapfig}
          \usepackage{tabu}
          \usepackage{mathtools}
          \usepackage{graphicx}
          \usepackage[english]{babel}
          \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
          \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
          \usepackage{parskip}
          \usepackage{graphicx}
          \usepackage{tabu}
          \usepackage{mathtools}
          \usepackage{graphicx}
          \usepackage{verbatim}
          \usepackage{subcaption}
          \usepackage{indentfirst}
          % Margins
         \usepackage[inner=2.0cm,outer=2.0cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
          % Colour table cells
          \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
          % Get larger line spacing in table
          \newcommand{\tablespace}{\\[1.25mm]}
          \newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
          \newcommand\tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.0ex}}         % = `top' strut
          \newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut


           \setlength{\marginparwidth}{2cm}
           \begin{document}
           \begin{center}
           \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|}
           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_1$} 
           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\color{blue}Player 2}\\
           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a_2$}  
           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$b_2$} \\
           \cline{3-4} 
           \multirow{2}*{\color{red}Player 1}  
           & $a_1$ 
           & $\textbf{(\color{red}{0}\color{black},\color{blue} 
           {0}\color{black})}$ 
           & $(\color{red}{6}\color{black},\color{blue}{-3}\color{black})$ \\
           \cline{3-4}
           & $b_1$ 
           & $(\color{red}{-3} \color{black},\color{blue}{6}\color{black})$ 
           & $(\color{red}{5} \color{black},\color{blue}{5}\color{black})$ \\
           \cline{3-4}
           \end{tabular}
           \end{center}


            \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{ccc|c|c|c|}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\omega_1$} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\color{blue}Player 2}\\
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$p$}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$1-p$}\\
  \cline{3-4} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$a_2$}  
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$b_2$} \\
    \cline{3-4} 
  \multirow{2}*{\color{red}Player 1}
  \multirow{1}*{q}
  \multirow{2}*{1-q}
    & $a_1$ 
         & $\textbf{(\color{red}{0}\color{black},\color{blue}{0}\color{black})}$ 
         & $(\color{red}{6}\color{black},\color{blue}{-3}\color{black})$ \\
        \cline{3-4}
    & $b_1$ 
          & $(\color{red}{-3} \color{black},\color{blue}{6}\color{black})$ 
          & $(\color{red}{5} \color{black},\color{blue}{5}\color{black})$ \\
    \cline{3-4}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You should provide a complete example, with the `\documentclass`, the `\begin{document}`, etc.

Comment: I am quite new, but posted a more complete version. Feedback on my post quality would be appreciated to improve my future posts.

Comment: Have you checked CTAN for packages related to game theory? There might already be something to easily typeset such tables, not to mention the probability trees you also mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way to do that table with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. I'm not sure to have understood exactly where you wanted rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}
 & & & \Block{1-2}{\color{blue}Player 2} \\
 & & & $p$ & $1-p$ \\
 & & & $a_2$ & $b_2$ \\
\Block{2-1}{\color{red}Player 1} 
& $q$ & $a_1$ & $({\color{red}0},{\color{blue}0})$ & $({\color{red}6},{\color{blue}-3})$ \\
& $1-q$ & $b_1$ & $({\color{red}-3},{\color{blue}6})$ & $({\color{red}5},{\color{blue}5})$ 
\CodeAfter
\tikz \foreach \x in {3,...,6} { \draw (\x-|3) -- (\x-|6) (3-|\x) -- (6-|\x) ; } ;
\end{NiceTabular}


\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

Just a slightly fixed-up version of your code that doesn't use TikZ; the output's visually very similar to that of F. Pantigny's answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|}
            & \multicolumn2c{} & \multicolumn2c{\color{blue}Player 2} \\
            & \multicolumn2c{} & \multicolumn1c{$p$} & \multicolumn1c{$1-p$} \\
            \cline{3-5}
            &&& $a_2$ & $b_2$ \\
            \cline{3-5}
            \multirow2*{\color{red}Player 1} &$q$ & $a_1$
            & $\textbf{(\color{red}{0}\color{black}, \color{blue}{0}\color{black})}$ 
            & $(\color{red}{6}\color{black}, \color{blue}{-3}\color{black})$ \\
            \cline{3-5}
            & $1 - q$ & $b_1$ 
            & $(\color{red}{-3} \color{black}, \color{blue}{6}\color{black})$ 
            & $(\color{red}{5} \color{black}, \color{blue}{5}\color{black})$ \\
            \cline{3-5}
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```